# CSS Div within a Div within yet another Div

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to figure out how to position a div within a div within another div. Is that even possible? I have seen a few articles on positioning a div within another div and none of them made sense to me. I am somewhat new to CSS and I'm still trying to grasp the concept.

Basically I'm trying to use positioned divs to create a custom table-like effect. I have my main div that is centered on the page 1000px wide and 1200px tall. Then I have another two divs within that one that separates it into left and right columns each 500px wide and 1200px tall. I have gotten that part easily. I am now trying to use another div in the right column to push my text down. On the top I have a picture that is 300px tall and 500px wide. I want the text to be just below the picture.

HTML code:

```
<div id="mbody" style="position:relative;">    

    <div id="lbody" style="position:absolute;">  

        Some Text

    </div>

    <div id="rbody" style="position:absolute; right:0;">  

        <img src="photo.jpg" height="300" width="500">

        <div style="position:absolute; width:500; height:1200; top:350;">

            Some Text

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#mbody{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:-73px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 1000px;
    height:1200px;
    background: black;
    z-index:1;
}
#lbody{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    left:0px;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:500px;
    height:1200px;
    background:black;
}
#rbody{
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:2px solid blue;
    width:500px;
    height:1200px;
    background:black;
}
```

Please keep in mind that I am new to css and still learning. If anyone answers can you please answer in such a way that even a beginner like me can understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For code, just use the {} button, or indent each line by 4 spaces. I've tidied it up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add '#' before all the div id names in your css 
eg. #mbody, #lbody, etc.

Only then will the html know that you are assigning values to the divs

Also, to have an image appear above the text on the right column can be achieved by
`<img src="photo.jpg" height="300" width="500" style="float:right;">`

Also, it usually helps during the design stage to give a background colour in the css
for eg.
`#lbody {background:red;}`
This will help you see how the css translates on screen.

Comment: i do have the # but i had to take it out because this site is wierd and was using the # as a formating thingy. i havent tried using the background colors but i will. i imagine it will be easier than just using the borders which is what i was using. i used <img src="photo.jpg" height="300" width="500" style=:float:right;>
 and it worked like a charm. thanks abunch.

Comment: Great! glad to help. good luck with the css :)   a quick tip for widths... if your main div is 1000, the left is 500, then the right should be 499. That extra margin of 1px always seems to help with the quirks of IE

Answer (score 1):

for a beginner to Css i would suggest you go through Css basics first ,best way to start is to refer head first with Css and Html book by O'Reilly .

Now talking about  tags and it's nesting you can nest as many divs u want provided u position them ,align them,float them is a proper way. Many attributes associated with div tag will help you out.

Next thing is for developing and viewing designing use Firefox's Firebug feature to keep track of height and widht properties and many cool things,so if you are using firefox please install FIREBUG a cool tool for designers ,gives u an edge in designing.

First go through basics.

Hope this might help.

Comment: I have gone through the basics quite a bit already. Ive been through the entire course on www.w3schools.com I was viewing this with firefox and it worked just fine. But then I try and work on this stuff at work on IE and it doesnt look so pretty. I had to add the !Doctype and readjust everything. Once I got it all readjusted the only thing I couldnt move were the divs inside the columns. No matter what I set as the top:xxx; value I couldnt get the little guy to move.

Comment: Yes the behaviour by IE is frustrating at times. For this best way is to use Conditional Css by Conditional comments which detects IE and renders the page by the css that runs properly for IE,so please go through conditional css too.